# Javascript - find 1-4-7, 2-5-8, 3-6-9 iretartions?

Tags: javascript, math, iteration

Iam trying to find the total height of 3 different columns of images

There are a total of 15 images

col1height should count the height of 1,4,7,10,13

col2height should count the height of 2,5,8,11,14

col3height should count the height of 3,6,9,12,15

Im a bit confused as how to calculate this

Javascript

```
        var gridContainerImage = document.querySelectorAll(".gridContainerImage");
        var col1height;
        var col2height;
        var col3height;

        for (var i = 0; i < gridContainerImage.length; i++) {
            var isFirstIteration = (i + 1) % 1 === 0;
            var isSecondIteration = (i + 1) % 2 == 0;
            var isThirdIteration = (i + 1) % 3 === 0;

            if (isFirstIteration) {
                alert(gridContainerImage[i].height);
            }
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="gridContainer" class="gridContainer">
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage1" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage3" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage4" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWfjLHUigNm0tYUqNrwFdwIr3ne33qMQYyR4F7F68fzEdtO0LptQ"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage5" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQE_D-CdD4DKs_8JApHnVmaqogB-nUdBnnDCjnOguyRhtAjAkUqrQ"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage6" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9Ng8KdJcE95oMHhnapV0ORQ72TP7mLNFzN2hvR4ymVwe8Qv1H0Q"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage7" src="http://www.miataturbo.net/attachments/insert-bs-here-4/35220d1330303876-random-pictures-thread-sfw-joe-stones-pony-random-shots-059-jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage8" src="http://files.sharenator.com/babykick_Random_Pics_P-s340x301-60511.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage9" src="https://www.nationalparkstraveler.org/sites/default/files/legacy_files/userhead/picture-56.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage10" src="http://cdn.simplesite.com/i/e8/0b/282600882889886696/i282600889577385650._szw1280h1280_.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage11" src="http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/MatRandom_12.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage12" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d6/f0/63d6f040b9dbbc5bbeb7cd238e8e0868.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage13" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5Tkt1aXq3kM/maxresdefault.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage14" src="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amazing-random-pictures-dumpaday-13.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="gridContainerImage" id="gridContainerImage15" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SX0VVRDhEbg/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro, every integer is divisible by 1 , so your code will always consider every iteration as 1st iteration.

Comment: Waow so many downvotes... thanks alot for struggeling with math...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for-loop should look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gridContainerImage.length; i++) {
        var isFirstIteration = i % 3 === 0;
        var isSecondIteration = i % 3 == 1;
        var isThirdIteration = i % 3 === 2;
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thats all? one sec :)

Comment: it's really works? when i = 1  isSecondIteration  must be true .... and it isn't...

Comment: Thanks man, got alot od DV tho :( but im thankfull for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gridContainerImage.length; i++) {
        var isFirstIteration = (i + 1) % 3 === 1;
        var isSecondIteration = (i + 1) % 3 === 2;
        var isThirdIteration = (i + 1) % 3 === 0;

        if (isFirstIteration) {
            alert(gridContainerImage[i].height);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could think about this differently. Correct me if I'm wrong but for the first column you actually want to produce the sequence 0,3,6... because arrays start from the number 0. So that's easy with a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; col < gridContainerImage.length; col += 3) {
    // do stuff with the first column here.
}
```

You could write similar loops for the other columns but it's simpler to wrap it all up in another loop. For example:

```
var colHeights = [0,0,0];
// for each column...
for (var col = 0; col < 3; col += 1) {
    // for each image in that column...
    for (var i = col; i < gridContainerImage.length; i += 3) {
        colHeights[col] += gridContainerImage[i].height;
    }
}
```

Now `colHeights[0]` should give you the height of the first column, and `colHeights[1]` for the second column and so on.